# django admin - adding fields on the fly

Tags: python, django, django-admin, shopping-cart, django-nonrel

Basically I am writing a simple shopping cart. Each item can have multiple prices. (i.e. shirts where each size is priced differently). I would like to have a single price field in my admin panel, where when the first price is entered, an additional price field pops up. However I am kind of at a loss as to how to do this. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want two related models - Item and Option. Item would contain the name of the item, and Option would contain the option - eg size - and the price of that option. You would then set up your admin to use an inline form for Option.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [inlines](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) and some javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You might try checking out the Satchmo codebase.  It has something similar that may provide some inspiration.   http://satchmoproject.com